# Xmpp server connection is not establishing in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

Using Jmeter i want to do load testing on Xmpp server.When i try to connect with server, the response  code is 200.But other criteria like connect time, latency, size in bytes,Sent bytes,Headers size in bytes are zero.Can anyone please help me in this issue.

**Sampler result:** 
Thread Name: Thread Group 1-1
Sample Start: 2019-09-19 14:52:54 IST
Load time: 501
Connect Time: 0
Latency: 0
Size in bytes: 20
Sent bytes:0
Headers size in bytes: 0
Body size in bytes: 20
Sample Count: 1
Error Count: 0
Data type ("text"|"bin"|""): text
Response code: 200
Response message: OK

SampleResult fields:
ContentType: 
DataEncoding: null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into [Connect](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/xmpp/src/main/java/com/blazemeter/jmeter/xmpp/actions/Connect.java#L21) action source code:

```
@Override
public SampleResult perform(JMeterXMPPSampler sampler, SampleResult res) throws Exception {
    AbstractXMPPConnection conn = (AbstractXMPPConnection)sampler.getXMPPConnection();
    conn.connect();
    res.setResponseData(sampler.getXMPPConnection().getConnectionID().getBytes());
    return res;
}
```

For **Connect** [action](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/xmpp/XMPPSampler.md#actions) the only thing you will be able to get is underlying [XMPPConnection](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/blob/master/smack-core/src/main/java/org/jivesoftware/smack/XMPPConnection.java) ID.

Smack library doesn't measure/report connect time, latency, etc. therefore XMPP sampler is not capable of displaying these metrics. So you will have to survive with [throughput, response time and % of errors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html).

Check out [XMPP Load Testing - The Ultimate Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/xmpp-load-testing-the-ultimate-guide/) article for more information on building XMPP test plans using JMeter.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri T,As u told i followed  XMPP Load Testing - The Ultimate Guide.But when i try to login, the response  code is 500.Returning null.                                              ERROR c.b.j.x.JMeterXMPPSampler: Error in XMPP Sampler: 
org.jivesoftware.smack.SmackException$NoResponseException: null